# How do I get pd.to_datetime() to take in multiple date formats?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling with getting `pd.to_datetime()` to take in multiple date formats and parse them. I thought it was taking in dates in different but similar formats, but it doesn't seem to do so. Here are two basic examples:

```
9/3/2020
9/2/20
```

And here's my script:

```
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(row['assignment_name'][:row['assignment_name'].find(' ')], "%m/%d/%y")
        due_date = row['assignment_name'][:row['assignment_name'].find(' ')]
        print(due_date)
        data_normalized.at[index, 'due_date'] = pd.to_datetime(due_date, format='%m/%d%y', errors='ignore')
    except ValueError as err:
        data_normalized.at[index, 'due_date'] = None
        print(err)
        continue
```

It reads the shorter format fine and parses it, but throws this error on the longer date format: `unconverted data remains: 20`.

I know I could clean the data a bit to get rid of the full year, but is there any way to add in multiple format parameters to the pandas function? Or what would be alternative solutions to read in multiple formats?

Comment: Why not try converting the date values first, then running those through `pd.to_datetime()`?

Comment: it;s not possible to add multiple formats, you have to clean up the data for one format. Because, if Datetime supports multiple formats, the function will be confused to take proper format value.

Comment: `to_datetime` function works on the two dates you give (pandas 1.0). 
`pd.to_datetime(['9/3/2020', '9/2/20'], errors='coerce') gives 
DatetimeIndex(['2020-09-03', '2020-09-02'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)`. Maybe I miss some elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas' native date parsing is fairly flexible. I had many times parsed dates in the format you provide, and it worked.

If I do a toy example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['9/3/2020', '9/3/20'], columns=['a'])
pd.to_datetime(df.a)

# Output
0   2020-09-03
1   2020-09-03
Name: a, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

It's working fine. I notice you have `format='%m/%d%y'`. This looks wrong to me (did you mean `%m/%d/%y`?). If you actually just remove `format` all together, pandas automatically picks it up.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I also had that `, errors='ignore'` parameter which was ignoring all the parsing issues that I was trying to catch so removing that helped.